# PubSub service having issue?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

It seems like api's are timing out when creating subscription for already existing topics. My tests which validate this was working until few minutes back but now they started failing. I am not even able to create subscription using Google's console either.

Though Google's dashboard shows service as working. Anyone else seeing this? I am not sure what else I can do to gather more info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we had an issue with error rates higher than expected around that time. The users should have seen 504 errors during the outage. As of 1:30PM, the issue has been resolved, and everything should be back to normal. Sorry about the inconveniences.

We do have SLA. Cloud Pub/Sub SLA is described here:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/sla

If you think you're eligible, you can request a refund from that page.

Sorry again for the inconveniences you may have had.

Comment: Not looking for refund but my concern is that Google's status page did not reflect the outage and we spent considerable time trying to figure out why our events were not making through.